# How to crack Caesar cipher without letter frequency analysis

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

I have implemented letter frequency analysis for cracking Caesar cipher in Java but it works for only big paragraphs of cipher text, the smaller the string gets probability of the shift and frequency weakens so is there any other mechanism for cracking? Please, some help would be useful.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not directly about programming, it is about [cryptography](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 4):

First technique that comes to mind:

1. Load a dictionary (or [*War and Peace*](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/2600/pg2600.txt) maybe) into a hash map.
2. Rotate the letters of your text 25 times (number of possible shifts), checking each time how many matches you find of the obtained words (after shifting letters) in the hash map.
3. The one with the most words found in map is probably the correct shift value for the cipher.

I am sure there are better, more efficient ways out there. This is what I came up with without searching the Internet.

Comment: i was looking for a more better method than freq analysis but i suppose brute force is only way other than that.

Answer (score 0):

The above technique is still letter frequency analysis. WITHOUT letter frequency analysis, I think there only thing left is a brute-force attack e.g. try to substitute each letter with a different one until the message become plain-text.

Comment: I think the other answer of Voicu is brute force. The only thing that is described with the dictionary is the *distinguisher*, that uses word frequency. That's different from frequency analysis of the ciphertext. Also note that "the above" does not adequately describe the other answer, just using a link would be better.